# Find a Session by ID Substring in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, session

Im trying to find a session by PART of its ID in laravel.

I only have the first part of the id, and I need to find if the session has a key/value associated with it.
I have tried various forms of the below code. Its fairly simple but not sure if possible in laravel.

Note

Im not sure if this helps or not, but the laravel system is using file based sessions, not DB based sessions.

```
        $value = 'do i have this value';

        // Session::all()->whereLike('id','aVhN8u' . '%')->get();

        foreach( Session::all()->where('id')->startsWith('aVhN8u') as $session)
        {
            if($session->has('key', $value)
            {
                // Do something interesting
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$value = 'my cool value';
$prefix = 'aVhN8u';
$stored = session()->all();

$filtered = collect($stored)->filter(function ($session, $key) use ($prefix, $value) {
    return Str::startsWith($key, $prefix) && $session == $value;
})->all();
```

Comment: thank you. This is exactly the type of thing I needed. I implemented it and hasnt worked so might be my code somewhere. Ill let you know shortly.

Comment: It wasnt working for me now I realize. , session()->all() is getting all the session data for a articular session. I need to get a List of al the files in `storage/framework/sessions/` All the Session IDs, not all the values of a session. So in part I guess I may have incorrectly worded the question.

Comment: @IEnumerable I think a better approach could be for you to use Cache to store values. So, you can tag elements (by user maybe) and then filter them for a specific value. Check this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#cache-tags

Comment: yes thanks, the mixture of the two is best for.  Thankyou I didnt even consider Cache